# React-Native not displaying background Image

Tags: react-native, background-image, imagebackground

I'm trying to set a background Image in React-Native but it is not appearing on my screen. However, the text inside `<ImageBackground></ImageBackground>` is getting displayed.
Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, ImageBackground, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <ImageBackground style={styles.container} source={require("./Assets/bg.png")}>
        <Text>Inside</Text>
    </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
    }
});
```

Here is my directory structure below. You can see there `bg.png` exists.
[image]

And Here is the output that I'm getting.
[image]

Here is my bg.png
[image]

I can't find what's wrong with this. Everything seems ok, Also I'm not getting any error message. Please Help

Comment: Can you add your image too?

Comment: @PritishVaidya Please see my edited answer, I just added the image that I'm trying to set as background

Comment: The app was crashing due to large canvas image rendering in android so i resized it to 25% and it worked.

Comment: But In my case, App was not crashing nor I was getting any error. Only the image was not appearing. that's it

Comment: Checkout this [link](https://snack.expo.io/Bkoie8V3G) both for android and ios

Comment: You're right. It worked. This tiny problem wasted my 6-7 hours. Thanks a lot. Post it as your answer so that I can accept it and others can also take the benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the link to the [expo](https://snack.expo.io/Bkoie8V3G).

It appears that there happens a crash in android for large images the bitmap becomes out of memory.

Therefore a workaround for that is to **resize** the image and use it.

For more info checkout this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)